# how can i make filter of tasks by name here?

Tags: vue.js

```
<template lang="pug">
.kanban
  .statuses
    .todo(@drop="onDrop($event,'todo')"
    @dragenter.prevent
    @dragover.prevent)
      span To do
        tasks-order-by-status(:tasks = 'taskTodo')
    .inprogress(@drop="onDrop($event,'inprogress')"
    @dragenter.prevent
    @dragover.prevent)
      span In Progress
        tasks-order-by-status(:tasks = 'taskInprog')
    .done(@drop="onDrop($event,'done')"
    @dragenter.prevent
    @dragover.prevent)
      span Done
        tasks-order-by-status(:tasks = 'taskDone')
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { TaskStatusEnum } from './../enums/TaskStatusEnum'
import TasksOrderByStatus from '@/components/TasksOrderByStatus.vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { emitter } from '../main'
import { TaskInterface } from '@/types/task.interface'
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
    const tasks = computed(() => store.state.tasks)
    return {
      tasks
    }
  },
  components: {
    TasksOrderByStatus
  },
  data () {
    return {
      TaskStatusEnum,
      showDetailsModal: false,
      task: '',
      taskTodo: [] as TaskInterface[],
      taskInprog: [] as TaskInterface[],
      taskDone: [] as TaskInterface[]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setArrayByStatuses () {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
        if (this.tasks[i].status === TaskStatusEnum.INPROGRESS) {
          const item = this.tasks[i]
          this.taskInprog.push(item)
        }
        if (this.tasks[i].status === TaskStatusEnum.TODO) {
          const item = this.tasks[i]
          this.taskTodo.push(item)
        }
        if (this.tasks[i].status === TaskStatusEnum.DONE) {
          const item = this.tasks[i]
          this.taskDone.push(item)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.setArrayByStatuses()
  }
})
</script>
```

how can i make filter of tasks by name here?
I tried to do this

```
computed: {
           filteredList () {
      return this.tasks.filter(task => {
        return task.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  },
```

but i have this error Property 'tasks' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>'.
Property 'tasks' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: { [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & ... 4 more ... & Co...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup() method does not work like you expect, it will not initiate data attributes (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-component-properties)
Use mounted() instead and assign
`this.tasks = tasks`
also add tasks to your data object.